# How to get a straight edge on subdivided object

Tags: edges, subdivision-surface

Hi is possible to get straight edges on a plane that has been subdivided without doubling up on the edges?

I understand how creases work etc.

[image]

Comment: Creases _would_ do the job...can we ask why you don't want to use them?

Comment: I have tried using creases but they don't straighten the corners.

Comment: Even if you crease the boundary edges?

Comment: Thanks Robin, by boundary edges I am pretty sure, I have if you look at the picture you can see I have highlighted every edge and set the crease to 1.0

Comment: Yup, I was just ruling out something silly like setting 'Bevel' or some other attribute of the edges, because I couldn't see the transform panel.. see my reply to your other comment.. it begins to look like a genuine beta-build-anomaly?

Comment: Thanks Robin, you are actually spot on. I have just tried the same method in Blender 2.7 and it works perfectly well. I don't normally use creases I normally just add the extra vertices but when I have a straight panel in an array I thought creases would be better.

Comment: or use Simple rather than Catmull-Clark subdiv. ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

..Trying to figure out what aspect of Crease is not doing what you would want it to ..

[image]

- The pink square is not subdivided.
- The grey square in the foreground is subdivided, all sides but the top one with a Crease value of 1. (Set on selected edges in the Transform panel, 'Mean Crease')
- On the right, all sides of the grey square with a Crease of 1, wires displayed.

(no Edge Split modifier)

Comment: What quality level do you have your subdivision set to? I only get this behavior when I set it to level 1. Higher quality levels it still rounds the corners.

Comment: @Rekov  Hmm.. works for me? I was talking 2.79, but in 2.8, build dated 2019-02-08, it works at all quality levels and subdivision levels... I've spent a little time trying to get it to fail, with an object just like yours, no success..

Comment: Hi all tried the same method in 2.7 and it worked fine. So it must be a beta thing. My beta is out of date it's from December 2018 sorry to waste peoples time.

Comment: @Mixstah np.. these things can get mystifying if there aren't other people around to try it too...

Comment: @RobinBetts Check this out: https://i.imgur.com/W0saNVV.gif This is what I mean. I used to see a much more pronounced difference in an older version too, where anything higher than '1' would round creased corners.

Comment: @Rekov   Got it... not happening in my 2.8 build...